# How can my aar library use its own third party libraries and doesn't have conflicts with main app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

We're developing a Android library which have a lot of third party libraries such Dagger2, Retrofit2, Glide and soon on. The library is going to distributed as AAR library in Github.

We are integrating our aar library, which is using a 2.0 retrofit version, in an app that uses an 1.9 retrofit version. As expected the aar library overwrites the version of the app to be older and changed to 2.0. And when we run the app, it crashes because doesn't found the 1.9 version.

The two version of third party libraries have to live in the same app and doesn't have conflict each other, so, when the library doesn't have to change the Retrofit version and the app which integrate the aar library, neither have to change the Retrofit version.

We're investigating about that and we found a possible solution which is using a [jarjar tool](https://github.com/vRallev/jarjar-gradle), but we don't know is the best solution. The other posibility is using the exlude dependencies or to use transitive dependencies which we've seen in this [page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Could anybody help us to integrated our library in apps in the best way without colide with the libraries of apps.

UPDATE: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1152

Comment: Retrofit 2.0.0 (final) uses a different package name than Retrofit 1.9. There shouldn't be any conflicts and you can use them both in the same project.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. We solved the Retrofit problem with the new version of Retrofit, but with Dagger 2 has conflicts with Dagger 1. So, we couldn't change the version of the sdk when a new conflict occurs.